# Anyone know how to use $CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM across different jobs in CircleCI?

Tags: docker, build-pipeline, circleci-2.0

I use `$CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM` in different jobs in a workflow (but it seems like that get incremented in between jobs of the same workflow)?

I did some research and it looks like I can switch to `CIRCLE_WORKFLOW_ID` which is unique for the workflow but then the ID is some really long string, not like the build number which is a small integer, nice that I can use to append to build numbers and docker tags and such.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

This is the approach I came up with.  It's kinda ugly, but it does work:

```
- run:
    name: Create unique build identifier
    command: |
        GIT_SHA=$( git rev-parse --short HEAD )
        echo "export GIT_SHA=${GIT_SHA}" >> "${BASH_ENV}"

        # the always-increasing counter, based on CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM
        BUILD_COUNTER="${CIRCLE_BUILD_NUM}"
        echo "export BUILD_COUNTER=${BUILD_COUNTER}" >> "${BASH_ENV}"

        # the build identifier, which includes the short git sha
        BUILD_NUMBER="CIRC${BUILD_COUNTER}-${GIT_SHA}"
        echo "export BUILD_NUMBER=${BUILD_NUMBER}" >> "${BASH_ENV}"

        # output build id and counter
        echo -e "\nbuild counter: ${BUILD_COUNTER}; build id: ${BUILD_NUMBER}\n"
```

Then `${BUILD_NUMBER}` is available as an environment variable in other steps.

Comment: `${BUILD_NUMBER}` won't be available in other jobs and this is what the question was about

Answer (score 0):

In v2.1 config you can use [pipeline values](https://circleci.com/docs/pipeline-variables/#introduction), specifically `pipeline.number`. This number is the same across all jobs in a workflow. (Indeed, across all workflows in the pipeline.) You can use it like this:

```yaml
    steps:
      - run: echo Hello from pipeline number << pipeline.number >>
```